# What would be a good way of displaying refreshing RGB Matrices on a single window in python?

Tags: python, performance

I need to display matrices onto a window, which refreshes at a high frequency. Is there a way of getting this done in python?

I have made use of pygame library to display a simple flashing screen. The work done is what I require, but the refresh rate is too low, which I believe has something to do with the bitwise operations for the matrices inside the program.

```py
import pygame, sys, random
import fetch_module
screen = ""
class Frontend:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.length = 1280
        self.height = 720
        if "length" in kwargs.keys():
            self.length = kwargs["length"]
        if "height" in kwargs.keys():
            self.height = kwargs["height"]

        #self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.length,self.height),flags=(pygame.FULLSCREEN|pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF))
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.length,self.height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Evolution')
        red = pygame.Color(250,255,250,0)
        zero = pygame.Color(0,0,0,0)
        self.buffer1 = [[int(red) for i in range(self.length)] for j in range(self.height)]
        self.buffer2 = [[int(zero) for i in range(self.length)] for j in range(self.height)]
        print("Init routine completed")
    def get_arr(self):
        resp = []
        buff = []
        if (self.ctr%2) == 0:
            #print("buff1")
            buff = self.buffer1
        else:
            #print("buff2")
            buff = self.buffer2
        for i in buff:
            for j in i:
                b =  j & 255
                g = (j >> 8 ) & 255
                r = (j >> 16) & 255
                a = (j >> 32) & 255
                resp.append(r)
                resp.append(g)
                resp.append(b)
                resp.append(a)
        #self.buffer1 = self.buffer2
        self.ctr+=1
        return bytes(resp)
    def service(self):
        print("Inside service routine")
        self.ctr = 0
        while True:
            buff = self.screen.get_buffer()
            buff.write(self.get_arr())
            pygame.display.update()
            if self.ctr == 10:
                break
            #self.buffer2 = fetch_module.fetch("http://localhost:8000",name="Evolution Frontend",height=self.height,length=self.length)
        pygame.quit()

front = Frontend()
front.service()
```

The framerate is approximately 1 frame/sec and it needs to be much higher than that.

Comment: Mapping the buffer to a rgb matrix can be done much faster if you use numpy arrays. However the 1fps is too low to blame python's slowness. Please use a python profiler to get info about your bottleneck. The code suggests that you are retrieving the buffer from the network. That would be slow.

Comment: Yes that is what I intend to do later on. This is a part of an analytical project that I am currently developing. The profilers failed to give me anything useful. Pycallgraph gives an error when called, it's unable to locate local modules for some reason. Profile generated by cProfile seems to have an error when attempting an open using runsnake, something about bad marshalling.